# Ubuntu 20.04 Wacom Stylus use causes immediate hang

Tags: 20.04, kernel, lenovo, wacom

After the latest updates, my Lenovo Yoga X390 hangs whenever I use Wacom Stylus. So far everything was ok till the recent kernel update. Now touching the screen with a stylus causes immediate os hang (had to do a hard reset).

Removing the Wacom kernel module solves the problem temporarily, as pen and touch work, but obviously, there is no pressure sensitivity.

```
$ lsmod | grep wacom
wacom                 118784  0
usbhid                 57344  1 wacom
hid                   135168  5 wacom,usbhid,hid_sensor_hub,intel_ishtp_hid,hid_generic
```

`dmesg` does not show any errors.

The kernel is:

```
Linux n317-pc01 5.8.0-45-generic #51~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Feb 23 13:46:31 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The bug is caused by updating kernel 5.8.0-44 to 5.8.0-45.
With kernel rolled-back to 5.8.0-44, the stylus works as expected.

I submitted a kernel bug report for the issue: https://bugs.launchpad.net/kernel-sru-workflow/+bug/1921052

The problem will be solved with the 5.8.0-49 kernel release. Please update to this kernel if you experience this behavior.

Comment: I have the same problem on a Lenovo Thinkpad X1 Yoga. 5.8.0-44 works as expected. The same problem occurs with the 5.8.0-48 kernel that I installed today. 5.8.0-49 works nicely.